# Navbar bar not updating to active when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple navbar that I am trying to get the background to be green when clicked. However it does not seem to be working.

When I hover over the link the background turns green and works fine. However I cannot get it so that when I click on the link the background remains green and if I click another link the new active turns green and the previous active turn white.

```js
$(".sidebar ul li").on("click", function() {
  $(".sidebar ul li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 276px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: #444444;
  padding: 4px 0px 4px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  border: 1px;
  border-collapse: #1aa322;
  background-color: #1aa322;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.sidebar li.active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #1aa322;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div id="logo">
    <IMG SRC="img/logo.png" ALT="Logo">
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="menu-header">
      <p>INTRODUCTION</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class="" id=menu>
      <a href="#Welcome">Welcome</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" id=menu>
      <a href="#Authentication">Authentication</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" id=menu>
      <a href="#Pagination">Pagination</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" id=menu>
      <a href="#Errors">Errors</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Right now when you click the link it is turning green and so on. I not getting what do you want expected o/p?

Comment: When I click it does nothing. If I click and move the mouse away, it got back to white background

Comment: From the provided code, it seems to have the desired result. I think you might have additional styling that is causing an issue. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dEmvOY

Comment: I can see when you click the link it is turning the background green. and when you click on another link the other bg is turning green and previous link goes to white bg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add jquery link to your code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(".sidebar ul li").on("click", function () {
    $(".sidebar ul li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 276px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: #444444;
  padding: 4px 0px 4px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  border: 1px;
  border-collapse: #1aa322;
  background-color: #1aa322;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.sidebar li.active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #1aa322;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
    <div id="logo">
        <IMG SRC="img/logo.png" ALT="Logo">
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="menu-header">
            <p>INTRODUCTION</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li class="" id=menu>
            <a href="#Welcome">Welcome</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id=menu>
            <a href="#Authentication">Authentication</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id=menu>
            <a href="#Pagination">Pagination</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id=menu>
            <a href="#Errors">Errors</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added your code here - it seems to work right.
Maybe something overlaps your navbar? Can it happen?

```js
$(".sidebar ul li").on("click", function () {
    $(".sidebar ul li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 276px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: #444444;
  padding: 4px 0px 4px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  border: 1px;
  border-collapse: #1aa322;
  background-color: #1aa322;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.sidebar li.active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #1aa322;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
    <div id="logo">
        <IMG SRC="img/logo.png" ALT="Logo">
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="menu-header">
            <p>INTRODUCTION</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li class="" id=menu>
            <a href="#Welcome">Welcome</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id=menu>
            <a href="#Authentication">Authentication</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id=menu>
            <a href="#Pagination">Pagination</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id=menu>
            <a href="#Errors">Errors</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason can be that when you click, what it gets clicked is the anchor element not the li.

You can add a class to your a tag and then target that class for the click function. And also modify the css to add the background when the a has the class.

So something like this for your anchor elements

```
<li>
   <a class="nav-link" href="#Welcome">Welcome</a>
</li>
```

Your css would look like

```
.sidebar .nav-link.active {
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: #1aa322;
 }
```

And your js would be like

```
$(".nav-link").on('click', function () {
    $(".nav-link").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Another reason could be that you ar executing your js before the elements are there. So try wrapping your code like.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sidebar ul li").on("click", function () {
        $(".sidebar ul li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Both solutions work.

And you should also not have the same id in multiple elements. So you should get rid of id="menu" or change it to be unique for each element